# SwipeRefreshLayout in both directions?

Tags: android

I love the new SwipeRefreshLayout! It looks great and its quite easy to use.
But i want to use it in both directions. I have a message screen and i want to 
load older messages by swiping from top to bottom and i want to load newer messages by swiping from bottom to top.

This example: http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/implementing-swipe-to-refresh/
explained quite easily how to get the top to bottom swiping but how can i implement that for both directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the source code https://github.com/futuresimple/android-support-v4/blob/master/src/java/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.java it's only listening to vertical changes (See `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`).

You should be able to override the class and implement this override yourself to enable it to listen to horizontal and vertical swipes but I don't think there's anything out of the box that allows you to do that.

The bit that should be of most interest is this:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
             if (mDownEvent != null && !mReturningToStart) { 
                 final float eventY = event.getY(); 
                 float yDiff = eventY - mDownEvent.getY(); 
                 if (yDiff > mTouchSlop) { 
                     // User velocity passed min velocity; trigger a refresh 
                    if (yDiff > mDistanceToTriggerSync) { 
                        // User movement passed distance; trigger a refresh 
                         startRefresh(); 
                         handled = true; 
                         break; 
                     } else { 
                         // Just track the user's movement 
                         setTriggerPercentage( 
                                 mAccelerateInterpolator.getInterpolation( 
                                         yDiff / mDistanceToTriggerSync)); 
                         float offsetTop = yDiff; 
                         if (mPrevY > eventY) { 
                             offsetTop = yDiff - mTouchSlop; 
                         } 
                         updateContentOffsetTop((int) (offsetTop)); 
                         if (mPrevY > eventY && (mTarget.getTop() < mTouchSlop)) { 
                             // If the user puts the view back at the top, we 
                             // don't need to. This shouldn't be considered 
                             // cancelling the gesture as the user can restart from the top. 
                             removeCallbacks(mCancel); 
                         } else { 
                             updatePositionTimeout(); 
                         } 
                         mPrevY = event.getY(); 
                         handled = true; 
                     } 
                 } 
             } 
             break;
```

*Please note that I do not recommend this approach. It's not standard interface and no one will expect it to work that way which can be confusing. Overriding this method in a custom layout also has the added risk that you may have to redo everything in the future when a new version comes out and you want to upgrade.*